# How to send keys to the file upload dialog in Selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

I'm doing this (using Watir on top of Selenium):

```
browser.span(:id => 'Upload').click
```

Pay attention, this is neither an `<input>` nor a `<button>`. It's just a `<span>`, which reacts (via some JavaScript) with a file upload dialog, which expects me to give it a file name. I need to send the file name into it and then hit `Enter`. How can I do this in Selenium?

I can't do this:

```
browser.span(:id => 'Upload').sendKeys(file)
```

Because I'm getting:

```
error: element not interactable
```

Comment: Include WATIR tag, people will come on your way to help you.

Comment: Please provide some Explicit Wait before interacting the element.

Comment: @KunduK He is using watir, so explicit wait for element to become visible is not necessary because that's automatic.

Comment: That's not the error I would expect. What happens when you click? Does it pop up the file upload dialog as expected? Fancy front end devs overwriting standard html behavior can make some of this especially challenging.

Comment: Do you have a hidden input field with `type=file` attribute and value in the page?

Comment: @supputuri yes, I do have that

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to upload the file.

```
browser.element(:css => "input[type='file']").sendKeys(file_path)
```